# Laptop detects extra monitor when there is none

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

My laptop (Samsung series 5 ultrabook) often detects an extra monitor when I haven't plugged anything in, causing the screen to essentially 'wrap round' for a second before adding another monitor, which I can't see but can move windows/the mouse over to, or sometimes completely freezing.

I'm unsure if this is a hardware or software issue. Is there a way to fix this/prevent it from happening? I'd be happy to completely disable the hdmi port if that would stop this happening.

Comment: Does your DE (which one?) have display or monitor settings, and something like "automatically configure new displays" that you can turn off?

Comment: Don't think so - I'm running Cinammon as my DE

Comment: I don't use cinammon often, but try watching dmesg and syslog (/var/log/syslog) for changes when it happens - a (ghost) hardware change might have some entries. There should be a desktop "errors" log somewhere too, maybe  a .file in home